# "Expected string, received object" Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, prisma, react-typescript, plumatic-schema

I'm creating a Help desk App, with Typescript, next, prisma, tailwind, and MySQL right now I'm dealing with the API call to save a ticket.

I received the following error:
"Expected string, received object" with a 400 bad request.

This is the code:

```
async function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof ticketSchema>) {
     try {
      setIsSubmitting(true);
      setError("");

      const distributor = {
        id: parseInt(values.distributor),
      };

      await axios.post("/api/tickets", {
        ...values,
        distributor: distributor,
        assignee: "",
      });
      router.push("/tickets");
      router.refresh();
    } catch (error) {
      setError("Uknown error ocurred");
    } finally {
      setIsSubmitting(false);
    }
  }
```

```
<Form {...form}>
        <form
          onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          className="space-y-8 w-full"
        >
          <div className="flex justify-between space-x-4">
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="distributor"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel> Distributor ID: </FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      placeholder="Distributor ID..."
                      {...field}
                      className=""
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
          <Controller
            name="description"
            control={form.control}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <SimpleMDE placeholder="Description" {...field} />
            )}
          />

          <Button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
            Create new ticket
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Form>
```

```
export const ticketSchema = z.object({
    distributor: z.string().min(1, "DIB-ID is requiered").max(8),
    phone: z.string().min(1, "Phone is requiered").max(10),
    email: z.string().min(1, "Email is requiered").max(100),
    source: z.string().min(1, "source is required").max(15),
    department: z.string().min(1, "department is required").max(30),
    topic: z.string().min(1, "topic is required").max(60),
    description: z.string().min(1, "description is required").max(65000),
    status: z.string().min(1, "Estatus").max(10).optional(),
    priority: z.string().min(1, "Priority").max(10).optional(),

})
```

when I check the type of what im sending it is a string but the error keep appearing.

```
console.log(typeof values.distributor) -> String
```

Do you guys have an advice? I have been stuck in here for 3 days lol.

I will appreciate any comment or advice!

tried to check what type I'm sending

Comment: I recommend using the Network pane in the browser to look at your payload rather than what the console log tells you. It might not be the 'distributor' field that's causing your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code when you are trying to make the post request.
Your schema expects you to have a `distributor` in your object that is a string. but when you are trying to send the post request, you are trying to send an object that contains an integer `id`:

```js
const distributor = {
   id: parseInt(values.distributor),
};

await axios.post("/api/tickets", {
    ...values,
    distributor: distributor, // this is an object but must be a string
    assignee: "",
});
```

the solution is easy. you have 2 options.

1. fix it from the request body:

```js
// const distributor = {
//    id: parseInt(values.distributor),
// };

await axios.post("/api/tickets", {
    ...values,
    distributor: values.distributor, // change it to the main value
    assignee: "",
});
```

2. or update your schema:

```js
export const ticketSchema = z.object({
    distributor: z.object({
        id: z.number().min(1).max(99999999)
    }),
    phone: z.string().min(1, "Phone is requiered").max(10),
    email: z.string().min(1, "Email is requiered").max(100),
    source: z.string().min(1, "source is required").max(15),
    department: z.string().min(1, "department is required").max(30),
    topic: z.string().min(1, "topic is required").max(60),
    description: z.string().min(1, "description is required").max(65000),
    status: z.string().min(1, "Estatus").max(10).optional(),
    priority: z.string().min(1, "Priority").max(10).optional(),
})
```